# Centralized access for config value management

Tags: node.js, configuration, environment-variables, aws-opsworks, centralized

We are using NodeJS as our codebase and all our config value is stored as `process.env.variable1`
Since our codebase is managed by AWS opsworks it takes almost 10 minutes to deploy config change on 1 machine and we have 23 machine likewise, is there any way through which all config values are stored at a centralised place and code access them without having latency also if there is any auto-refresh mechanism present so that we access the new config value in realtime.